# Integral for marginal density of transformed rv doesn't converge

Tags: probability, integration, probability-theory, probability-distributions, improper-integrals

I am given the following joint pdf of the two random variables $X$ and $Y$:
$$
f_{XY}(x,y) = 
        \begin{cases}
         1 & \text{for } 0 < x,y < 1 \\
            0 & otherwise
        \end{cases}
$$
and let $U = X$ and $V=X/(1-Y)$.

Ultimately, I need to find the marginal densities $f_U(u)$ and $f_V(v)$.

First I solve for $X$ and $Y$ in terms of $U$ and $V$:
$$
X = U \\
Y = -\frac{U-V}{V}
$$

And I find that the support for $U,V$ is $0 \leq u \leq 1$, $0 \leq v \leq \infty$, $u \leq v$.

Now I find the joint pdf $f_{UV}(u,v)$:
$$
J = \left|\begin{array}{cc} \frac{\partial x}{\partial u} & \frac{\partial y}{\partial u} \\ \frac{\partial x}{\partial v} & \frac{\partial y}{\partial v} \end{array}\right| \\
= \left|\begin{array}{cc} 1 & -\frac{1}{v} \\ 0 & \frac{u}{v^2} \end{array}\right| \\
= (1)(\frac{u}{v^2}) - (-\frac{1}{v})(0) \\
= \frac{u}{v^2} + \frac{1}{v} \\
|J| = \frac{u}{v^2} + \frac{1}{v} \\
$$

$$
            f_{UV}(u,v) = f_{XY}\left(u, \ -\frac{u-v}{v}\right)|J| \\
                   = 
                            \begin{cases}
              1\left(\frac{u}{v^2} + \frac{1}{v}\right) & \text{for support of } u,v \\
                 0 & otherwise
             \end{cases} \\
                            = 
                            \begin{cases}
              \frac{1}{v} &  0 \leq u \leq 1, \ 0 \leq v \leq \infty, \ u \leq v \\
                 0 & otherwise
             \end{cases} \\
$$

Now I attempt to find the marginal densities for $U$ and $V$:
$$
f_V(v) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{UV}(u,v) du \\
                  = \int_{0}^{1} \frac{u}{v^2} + \frac{1}{v} du \\
                        = \left[ \frac{u^2}{2v^2} + \frac{u}{v} \right]_0^{1} \\
                        = \left( \frac{1^2}{2v^2} + \frac{1}{v} \right) - \left(\frac{0^2}{2v^2} + \frac{0}{v} \right) \\
                        = \frac{1}{2v^2} + \frac{1}{v} \\
                        = \frac{1 + 2v}{2v^2} \\
$$

$$
f_U(u) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{UV}(u,v) dv \\
                  = \int_{u}^{\infty} \frac{u}{v^2} + \frac{1}{v} dv \\
                        = \left[ -\frac{u}{v} + log(v) \right]_u^{\infty} \\
                        = \left( -\frac{u}{\infty} + log(\infty) \right) - \left( -\frac{u}{u} + log(u) \right) \\
                  = \left( -\frac{u}{\infty} + log(\infty) \right) - \left( -1 + log(u) \right) \\
= \infty
             \\
$$

But the integral for finding the marginal density of $U$ does not converge. Have I made a mistake in finding the support of $U$ and $V$, or in the process of finding the joint and marginal densities of $U$ and $V$?

Comment: Wrong Jacobian $|J|$.

Comment: @Did Thanks, I've corrected the Jacobian and subsequent integrals. But I am still finding that the marginal for $U$ does not converge?

Comment: Your Jacobian is still wrong. *Hint:* what is zero multiplied by $1/v$?

Comment: D'oh, of course. I need some sleep... thanks